# Kotlins extension method Stream.toList() is missing

Tags: collections, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I'm trying to convert a stream to a correctly typed list in kotlin. For this case kotlin provides the extension method [Stream.toList()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.streams/java.util.stream.-stream/to-list.html). This method is located in *kotlin.streams*. The IDE (IntelliJ) does not allow to call this method on a stream. Do I have to add a special dependency or should it be part of the standard library? I'm using maven and there is a dependency to kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 1.2.10.

Note: The stream is returned from a library function so I have to work with it. Please no answers like "in kotlin you do not use streams...".

Comment: you need to add `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` & set `jvmTarget=1.8` in build.gradle

Comment: It is maven. `kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget` property is set to "1.8". Thought this would be enough?

Comment: have you refresh the maven project? if you don't know how to do, just write the code manually and move the cursor at the error code press `ALT+ENTER` try to fix it. you also need to update `maven-compiler-plugin` to `<source>1.8</source>`.

Comment: With Idea 2018.1 an Kotlin Plugin 1.2.30 or 31 this bug seems to be fixed. I cannot reproduce the problem any more...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue if I'm using the `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` dependency instead of `kotlin-stdlib-jre8` (which we're [not supposed to be using](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#kotlin-standard-library-artifacts-and-split-packages) from 1.2 and up).

It does, however, work if I manually add the import:

```
import kotlin.streams.toList
```

Also make sure that you've updated your Kotlin plugin to the latest version, it might also help. There's definitely something wrong with the import not being found automatically though.

Comment: You got it! Thank you! It works with the import. The plugin version and idea are uptodate (1.2.20 and 2017.3.2). Should I open a bug report for idea?